# Using ngModel inside an ngFor loop

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular-ngmodel

I am using `ngModel` inside of an `ngFor` loop to get values from a dropdown menu, like so:

```
<div *ngFor="let group of groups">
  <select [(ngModel)]="selectedOption">
          <option *ngFor="let o of options">
            {{o.name}}
          </option>
        </select>
  <p>Selected option: {{ selectedOption }}</p>
<div>
```

When I pick a selection from the dropdown, it sets all the other dropdowns to the same value. This is expected behavior, since `ngModel` is bound to `selectedOption` on all the instances created by the `ngFor` loop.

My question is, what is a good method for uncoupling different dropdowns within a loop so that they act independently?

Stackblitz is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xvqaeg?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Please check my code and let me know does it resolve your problem or not. Best wishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy solution is to bind the selected option to the group as follows.

1. Create a new interface:

   interface Group {
   name: string;
   selectedOption?: string;
   }
2. Change the groups' type to an array of Group:

   groups: Group[] = [{ name: "Group1" }, { name: "Group2" }];
3. Change the ngModel binding:

   <select [(ngModel)]="group.selectedOption">

You can find my solution [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wpdjnd?file=app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 1):

You are binding the same property to all the dropdowns.

If you want to do this with a loop then you need an array. `selectedOptions: string[] = [];` instead of `selectedOption: string;`

And need little change in the typescript part too.

Follow my workaround of the problem at [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ijczjl?file=app/app.component.html).

Answer (score 1):

My preferred way would be to make it an own component:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let group of groups">
   <app-group [group]=group [options]=options></app-group>
</ng-container>
```

GroupComponent Template:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedOption">
          <option *ngFor="let o of options">
            {{o.name}}
          </option>
        </select>
  <p>Selected option: {{ selectedOption }}</p>
```

GroupComponent TS file look somewhat like this:

```
@Component({
...
})

@Input(): group: Group;
@Input(): options: any[]; // Whatever the data type of option is

selectedOption: any;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use a custom class to solve your issue. Because you can declare a `selectedOption` for each specific group. Here is my code below.
**Please check the link:** [Demo Link StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g2n9vb?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts).

**HTML:**

```
<div *ngFor="let group of mygroups">
  <select [(ngModel)]="group.selectedOption" (ngModelChange)="checkChange($event,group)">
          <option *ngFor="let o of options">
            {{o.name}}
          </option>
        </select>
  <p>Selected option: {{ group.selectedOption }}</p>
</div>
```

**TS:** Custom Group Class

```
export class MyGroup{
  id:number;
  name:string;
  selectedOption:any;
}
```

Code Inside your `AppComponent` =>

```
mygroups: MyGroup[] = [];

  options = [
    { name: "option1", value: 1 },
    { name: "option2", value: 2 }
  ]
  constructor(){
    for(let i=1;i<=2;i++){
      let temp= new MyGroup();
      temp.id=i;
      temp.name='N-'+i;
      this.mygroups.push(temp);
    }
  }
  checkChange($event,grp){
    console.log("GRP:"+grp.name);
    console.log("Data:"+$event);
  }
```

**Note:** I have changed and updated few things in your code in stackblitz.